# Cannot seem to get my While statement to work

Tags: c, arrays, while-loop

so I am trying to write a program that asks the user for a word or phrase and then gives the scrabble value of the word. The problem that I am running into is that the program's while loop needs to close when the user inputs only the letter "q" or "Q" as the word/phrase.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string>
#include<conio.h>
```

This is the function that determines the letter worth

```
int scrabbleValue(char* word)
{

    int value = 0;
    int scrabbleTot = 0;
    int index = 0;

    while (*(word + index) != '\0')
    {
        switch (toupper(*(word + index)))
        {
        case 'A':
        case 'E':
        case 'I':
        case 'L':
        case 'N':
        case 'O':
        case 'R':
        case 'S':
        case 'T':
        case 'U':
            value = 1;
            break;
        case 'D':
        case 'G':
            value = 2;
            break;
        case 'B':
        case 'C':
        case 'M':
        case 'P':
            value = 3;
            break;
        case 'F':
        case 'H':
        case 'V':
        case 'W':
        case 'Y':
            value = 4;
            break;
        case 'K':
            value = 5;
            break;
        case 'J':
        case 'X':
            value = 8;
            break;
        case 'Q':
        case 'Z':
            value = 10;
            break;
        }
        scrabbleTot += value;
        *word++;
    }
    return scrabbleTot;

}
```

The good ol main statement

```
int main()
{
    char *ptr;
    char check;
    int wordvalue;

    char name[100];

    printf("\nEnter a word :");

    scanf("%s", name);

    ptr = name;
    check = name[0];
    wordvalue = scrabbleValue(ptr);
    printf("Your word value is: %d\n", wordvalue);
```

Here is where I am having trouble. I cannot seem to get this while loop to work properly. I tried string compare of name[0] and "q" but it will not compile.

```
    while (!strcmp() || !strcmp(name, "Q"))
    {
        printf("\nEnter a word :");
        scanf("%s", name);
        ptr = name;

        wordvalue = scrabbleValue(ptr);
        printf("Your word value is: %d\n", wordvalue);
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `!strcmp()`?  Also if you are using C++ you should use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) when working with strings.

Comment: What does `!strcmp()` do?????

Comment: Does `!strcmp()` compile ? It shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want this main function. It's much simpler without useless variables and without duplicated code.

```
int main()
{
    int wordvalue;
    char name[100];

    while (1)
    {
        printf("\nEnter a word :");
        scanf("%s", name);

        if (strcmp(name, "Q") == 0)
          break;

        wordvalue = scrabbleValue(name);
        printf("Your word value is: %d\n", wordvalue);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is untested code, it may not compile and there may be typos.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `while (!strcmp() || !strcmp(name, "Q")) {`, which seems wrong, you can use the following simpler piece of code:

```
while (!(tolower(name[0]) == 'q' && name[1] == '\0')) {
```

Comment: @RichAngal Glad I could help. Consider accepting the answer if it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it. `while` should have been:

```
while (strcmp(name,"q") && strcmp(name,"Q")) {
```

From `strcmp` you get `0` (implicitly converted to false) when the values are equal. You want the value to be neither "q", nor "Q" for the loop to continue (both must return non-zero, or true), so only `while (true && true)` will continue.

So full `main` would be:

```
int main()
{
    char *ptr;
    char check;
    int wordvalue;

    char name[100];

    printf("\nEnter a word :");

    scanf("%s",name);

    ptr = name;
    check = name[0];
    wordvalue = scrabbleValue(ptr);
    printf("Your word value is: %d\n",wordvalue);
    while (strcmp(name,"q") && strcmp(name,"Q")) {
        printf("\nEnter a word :");
        scanf("%s",name);
        ptr = name;

        wordvalue = scrabbleValue(ptr);
        printf("Your word value is: %d\n",wordvalue);
    }
    return 0;
}
```